# Embed PDF In Dexterity File View

Tags: plone, dexterity

I want a quick and easy (plugin dependent) PDF embedded view, not just a download link for File items.

My custom File schema looks like:

```
class IBulletin(form.Schema):
    ...

    form.primary('file')
    file = NamedBlobFile(
        title=_(u"File"),
        required=False,
    )

class Bulletin(Item):
    grok.implements(IBulletin, IFile)
```

I follow instruction at http://www.kcsts.co.uk/blog/embedded-pdf-in-file-view-with-plone and it works for Archetypes File view, but seems not working for Dexterity File view.

I guess the critical part is within `<object ...>` and `<embed ...>`. My trial to the template looks as follows:

```
<metal:content-core define-macro="content-core"
   tal:define="content_type context/file/contentType|nothing;
               location string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/file/${context/file/filename};
               v python:context.restrictedTraverse('contenttype_utils');">

<object class="viewembededfile" type="application/pdf" data=""
 tal:condition="python:content_type.endswith('pdf')"
 tal:attributes="data location; width string:100%; height string:900">
  <a href="" tal:attributes="href location">Please click here to download the PDF.</a>
  <embed src="" class="viewembededfile" type="application/pdf"
   tal:attributes="src location">
  </embed>
</object>
...
```

I also tried `<object ... attributes="data context/absoulte_url;"` and `<embed ... attributes="src context/absolute_url"` but does not work. It shows only a block with gray background. See the image for reference.

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried do something like see in [Dexterity Doc](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/files-and-images.html), but show box gray with `problem to load PDF`, I think @Mathias can help us.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and after some trial and error, I found out that if I don't include the file name at the end of the location of the pdf file then at least Firefox starts to show the embedded pdf.

```
<object type="application/pdf"
    tal:attributes="data string:${context/absolute_url}/@@download/file">
</object>
```

Same applies for links to the pdf file, with file name a download dialog is shown, and without the pdf file is rendered inside Firefox.